# Ros2 humble error ,roslaunch module not found

Tags: ros2

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPQZ8.png)when i run the following gazebo launch file i see the following error as shown in the image what should i do?

> Actually i created a launch file containing the [controller.py](/questions/tagged/controller.py) that would control my gazebo simulation and [gazebo.launch.py](/questions/tagged/gazebo.launch.py) but i am not getting why '[tag:roslaunch'] is not found is there any mistake while installation ?